# Regardless of the concurrency specified, RabbitMQ listener starts only one thread per consumer if the queue is nonempty but is not receiving messages

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.3 with the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I configured a single Rabbit consumer in my project, and tried setting the concurrency both through application.properties:

spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency=4

and through the concurrency attribute of the @RabbitListener annotation.

In both cases I see exactly the same behaviour (I am running the Spring Boot application on Windows): if the queue being listened to already contains messages, but is not currently receiving any, only one thread begins processing the messages from the queue.

If then I send some  new messages to the queue, indeed additional threads are started to process the messages (so that their total number is 4 in my case as specified).

Is there some additional configuration to do in order to start processing the messages already in a queue which is not currently receiving messages, by the specified number of threads?

Comment: Try to set `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch=1`. It is `250` by default, so it might be a fact that one consumer is prefetching all the message from your queue. Therefore left nothing for all other consumers.

Comment: However, something larger than 1 is preferred, for optimum performance.

Comment: thank you, this resolved the issue.